# Opensource platform for prediction market software, Hubdub.com clone etc

Tags: open-source

I used to be a frequent player on hubdub.com, where you could 'predict' (or bet on) the news.  Hubdub sadly closed in April, but I've been considering something on a much smaller scale for a different domain.

My question is - are there any working prediction software clone tools out there that you can easily configure, setup for many users, many topics and scales well?  Like pligg is to digg.com, I'm after prediction market software.

I've looked at Zocalo, but it's a bit too academic.  [Bookmaker](http://drupal.org/project/bookmaker) has too many bugs open and hasn't been developed in years, and [Prediction Market](http://drupal.org/project/pm) and [Betting System](http://drupal.org/project/betting) are still in their infancy and don't have working websites successfully based on their software as an example.

Any suggestions welcomed, if I have to code the whole thing up myself fine, but I'd hate to be reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module for [drupal](http://drupal.org/project/market), but the development seems to have stalled. Anyway, from what I have been looking at, there are no viable off-the-shelf open source prediction market products.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Drupal based solutions, but I believe they are all in various states of disrepair. I wrote [a post about them](http://openpredictionmarkets.org/blogs/greggles/list-drupal-based-market-makers-prediction-market-focused-or-otherwise-prediction-mar) a while ago and it's still pretty accurate. Certainly one or more of them could be a basis for great work.

There is also [Zocalo](http://zocalo.sourceforge.net/) which has been going relatively strong since 2005. Zocalo is, however, a Java based application which, in my opinion, makes it inaccessible to most people who "just want to setup a site."

Answer (score 0):

http://ideafutures.sourceforge.net/

Relatively old and not active, but the code is there (PERL)

Runs http://ideosphere.com/ (probably the oldest prediction market on the Web)